# Improving the POV definition in the listings package

Tags: listings, highlighting

I'm attempting to create a language definition in the `listings` package that mimics exactly the syntax highlighting in POV-Ray 3.6 for Windows (http://www.povray.org/download/).  Here is a screenshot from POV, which I'm trying to imitate:

[image: correct syntax highlighting]

(The POV language definition in the `listings` package is not the same.)

I include below my attempt so far, but it has some flaws.  First, I cannot get it to make numbers green, despite my attempt.  Second, I cannot get it to make angle brackets (or other operators) red, despite my attempts.  By contrast, my attempt to get curly braces to show up blue works fine, despite its similarity to the angle brackets problem/solution.  I am obviously doing something wrong, but reading the reference manual for the `listings` package didn't clear up my confusion.

Here's an example of my wrong results:

[image: incorrect syntax highlighting]

Any tips?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{povcodered}{rgb}{0.75,0.25,0.25}
\definecolor{povcodegreen}{rgb}{0.25,0.75,0.25}
\definecolor{povcodeblue}{rgb}{0.25,0.25,0.75}
\definecolor{povcodepurple}{rgb}{0.5,0,0.35}
\definecolor{povcodebluegreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0.5}

\lstdefinelanguage{myPOV}{
    alsoletter={\#\{\}\<\>},
    keywords={
        sphere, cone, and, so, on,
        \#include, \#declare, \#version},
    keywords={[2]\{,\}},
    keywords={[3]\<,\>},
    sensitive=true,
    string=[b]{"},
    comment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/}}

\lstset{language=myPOV,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=\color{povcodepurple},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{povcodeblue},
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{povcodered},
    stringstyle=\color{povcodered},
    commentstyle=\color{povcodegreen},
    numberstyle=\color{povcodebluegreen}}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
#include "somefile.inc"
// now let's add a shape
sphere {
  <0,0,0>, 1
  translate <5,3,2>
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. While solving problems is fun, setting them up is not. Then those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving problem.

Comment: Also, please use a supported image format, and provide the correct and incorrect image for the _same_ code snippet so it is easier to compare (and include the code snippet in your [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)). You should edit your question and upload the pictures using the picture icon button, and remove the `!`. Then other higher rep users here can simply remove the `!` and you image will show up.

Comment: I've made edits in accordance with these directions. Feel free to put the exclamation points back in. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [your self-answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82738/21891), it seems you're almost there. The last remaining problem is to highlight `/` and `//` differently and make sure `//` starts a comment.

### How to highlight `/` and `//` differently (without breaking comments)

As you've noticed, any literate replacement of `/` will prevent you from using it in a comment delimiter; therefore, you have to resort to other means than a literate replacement of `/`. The approach shown in the code below solves the problem.

**Caveat**: if `//` is immediately preceded by a character that `listings` treats as "other" (for instance, `*//`), `//` will still start a comment but it won't be highlighted in comment style.

### Side note: don't define `{` and `}` as "letters"

Defining `{` and `}` as "letters" via

```
alsoletter = {\{\}},
```

is a bad idea, at least in your case. Here is an example of where it could go wrong: `listings`, if it encounters the sequence of characters `sphere{` (note the absence of space between `sphere` and `{`), would recognise it as a *single* identifier; the `sphere` part would not be recognised as a keyword and would therefore not be get highlighted as such. Here, literate replacements of `{` and `}` are preferable.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %<--- for nice braces in typewriter font
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\lstdefinelanguage{myPOVlanguage}
{
  alsoletter  = {\#},
  keywords    =
  {
    \#include, \#declare, \#version,
    assumed_gamma,
    background, box,
    camera, color, color_map, cone, cylinder,
    direction,
    function,
    global_settings, gradient,
    light_source, location, look_at,
    matrix,
    no_shadow,
    object,
    pigment, pow,
    rgb, right, rotate,
    scale, sphere,
    translate, 
    x, y, z,        
  },
  sensitive   = true,
  string      = [b]{"},
  comment     = [l]{//},
  morecomment = [s]{/*}{*/},
}

% --- color definitions ---
\definecolor{povcodered}{rgb}{0.75,0.25,0.25}
\definecolor{povcodegreen}{rgb}{0.25,0.75,0.25}
\definecolor{povcodeblue}{rgb}{0.25,0.25,0.75}
\definecolor{povcodepurple}{rgb}{0.5,0,0.35}
\definecolor{povcodebluegreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0.5}

\lstdefinestyle{myPOVstyle}
{
  language           = myPOVlanguage,
  frame              = single,
  framextopmargin    = 3mm,
  framexbottommargin = 3mm,
  basicstyle         = \ttfamily\bfseries,
  keywordstyle       = \color{povcodepurple},
  stringstyle        = \color{povcodered},
  commentstyle       = \color{povcodegreen}\itshape,
  literate =*
    {0}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}0}}}1
    {1}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}1}}}1
    {2}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}2}}}1
    {3}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}3}}}1
    {4}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}4}}}1
    {5}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}5}}}1
    {6}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}6}}}1
    {7}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}7}}}1
    {8}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}8}}}1
    {9}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}9}}}1
    {+}{{{\color{povcodered}+}}}1
    {-}{{{\color{povcodered}-}}}1
    {*}{{{\color{povcodered}*}}}1
    {<}{{{\color{povcodered}<}}}1
    {>}{{{\color{povcodered}>}}}1
    {\{}{{{\color{povcodeblue}\{}}}1
    {\}}{{{\color{povcodeblue}\}}}}1
}

% --- patch to get proper highlighting of / and // ---
\makeatletter
\lst@AddToHook{OutputOther}
{%
  \edef\@tempa{\the\lst@token\relax}%
  %
  % apply \color{povcodered} if / is found
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\@firstoftwo\@tempa/%
    \def\lst@thestyle{\color{povcodered}}%
    %
    % apply comment style if // is found
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\@secondoftwo\@tempa/%
      \def\lst@thestyle{\lst@commentstyle}%
    \fi  
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\lstset{style=myPOVstyle}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
#include "somefile.inc"
// now let's add a shape
sphere {
  <0,0,0>, 1
  translate <5,3,2>

  sdf/sdf
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This did indeed solve the slash problem, so I'm going to mark it as the correct answer.  However, in my document, curly braces render in the normal document's font, not in the ttfamily, as they do in yours.  Should I start a separate question for that?  Sorry, not sure what the protocol is...

Comment: Did you use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?

Comment: Boy that really proves that I should read the whole solution, doesn't it?  Thanks, that (embarrassingly) fixed it!

Comment: @Nathan No problem `:)` Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've mostly answered my own question.  By reading some of the other related questions I cobbled together the following POV language definition file that does most of what I want, or at least is extensible enough that it will be able to do most of what I want after it's done evolving.

The essential fix was to use `literate` in a way that's not really its intended use, but just as a generic mechanism for replacing any character sequence with any other.  This allows me to choose specific digits, operators, etc., and assign them colors.

Here is POV code that isn't fully complete (not all operators and keywords) but I'll extend it as I hit new operators and keywords that aren't on this list.  You get the idea.  The code is below.

The one thing that ***isn't*** yet solved by this is that the double-slash for a one-line comment is now treated like two adjacent single-slashes, so there is no such thing as a one-line comment anymore.  It seems that `literate` overrides everything else.  That question therefore remains.

```
\lstdefinelanguage{myPOV}{
    alsoletter={\#\{\}},
    keywords={
        sphere, cone, cylinder, box, object,
        rotate, translate, scale, matrix,
        camera, location, direction, right, look_at,
        pigment, gradient, color_map, color, rgb,
        x, y, z, pow, function,
        light_source, background, no_shadow,
        global_settings, assumed_gamma,
        \#include, \#declare, \#version},
    keywords={[2]\{,\}},
    sensitive=true,
    string=[b]{"},
    comment=[l]{//},
    morecomment=[s]{/*}{*/},
    literate=%
       *{0}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}0}}}1
        {1}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}1}}}1
        {2}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}2}}}1
        {3}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}3}}}1
        {4}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}4}}}1
        {5}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}5}}}1
        {6}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}6}}}1
        {7}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}7}}}1
        {8}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}8}}}1
        {9}{{{\color{povcodebluegreen}9}}}1
        {+}{{{\color{povcodered}+}}}1
        {-}{{{\color{povcodered}-}}}1
        {*}{{{\color{povcodered}*}}}1
        {/}{{{\color{povcodered}/}}}1
        {<}{{{\color{povcodered}<}}}1
        {>}{{{\color{povcodered}>}}}1}

\lstset{language=myPOV, frame=single,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=\color{povcodepurple},
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{povcodeblue},
    stringstyle=\color{povcodered},
    commentstyle=\color{povcodegreen},
    framextopmargin=3mm,
    framexbottommargin=3mm
    }
```

Comment: Move the definition of `comment=[l]{//}` behind the assignment of `{/}{{{\color{povcodered}/}}}1`, i.e. move it behind all literate assignments. A similar case can be found somewhere in the `listings` documentation.

Comment: @Speravir: This did not make a difference.  The literate assignments, even if they are put before the comment= lines, seem to take precedence over them.

Comment: Aah, I forgot, that the comment sign itself is not in markup. But you could include a second `literate` entry behind the existing one with `{//}{{<your wanted formatting>}}2`, see in the manual under “Literate Programming”. BTW according to this you have one too many pair of braces in each of your entries. And add this into the answer!

Comment: And: What I’ve overread in the manual until now: “The optional star indicates that literate replacements should not be made in strings, comments, and other delimited text.”, a reminder there would be useful, that this does not apply to the comment/string/delimiter signs themselves (--> kind of bug report).