# Why don't those non-alphanumeric chars (*/_) get colored in blue, here?

Tags: listings, highlighting

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{language=R,
    morecomment=[l]{>},
    commentstyle=\color{blue},
    alsoletter={*}
    }
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
> q_A=0:6
> q_B=6-q_A
> N_A=6
> N_B=4
> (factorial(q_A+N_A-1)/(factorial(q_A)*factorial(N_A-1)))
[1]   1   6  21  56 126 252 462
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

The above code compiles to a simplified version of the image below (from the main document):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/D3rkYpZ.png?1]

When compiling this, the asterisk `*`, the underscore `_`, and the slash `/` are all still treated as special characters that should *not* be highlighted. I've already included the `alsoletter` key to include e.g. `*`, but the key seems to be ignored. How can I get the entire line starting with a `>` to be blue?

I've already checked e.g. [How can I get identifier style to apply to '%' (in a Perl listing)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142582/how-can-i-get-identifier-style-to-apply-to-in-a-perl-listing) for special identifiers, but that doesn't seem to work here. Neither does the "normal" approach of simply using `alsoletter=*` or `alsoletter={/}`, etc.

Where is it going wrong?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186092/how-can-i-delete-non-letter-keywords-such-as

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from how the `listings` language for `R` is defined. If you look up the definition in [lstdvrs.dtx](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/lstdrvrs.dtx) (search for `\lst@definelanguage{R}`), you'll see that `*`, `/`, and `_` are all defined as "otherkeywords":

```
otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,*,\&,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-,_,/},%
```

I refer you to this [other answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186092/how-can-i-delete-non-letter-keywords-such-as/186095#186095) to understand why this is problematic, and what can be done about it.

I don't think you actually want to declare `*` as a "letter", here (at least, that's not necessary for `*` to be coloured in blue like the rest of the line). There are nasty side effects to that; see the side note in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164634/21891.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    language=R,
    otherkeywords={},
    otherkeywords={!,!=,~,$,\&,\%/\%,\%*\%,\%\%,<-,<<-},
    morecomment=[l]{>},
    commentstyle=\color{blue},
}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
> q_A=0:6
> q_B=6-q_A
> N_A=6
> N_B=4
> (factorial(q_A+N_A-1)/(factorial(q_A)*factorial(N_A-1)))
[1]   1   6  21  56 126 252 462
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is too easy...